# invoke-command Passing of data/variables in and passing changed and new data/variables out

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I'm trying to pass some variables sort-of similar to the below, but it isn't passing back the updated/change data i want.  In the small example below can you state the way this should be written to be able to pass the data in and back as shown?

```
    $myfirstname = Jos
    $sess = new-pssession -computername "superdooperkompooter.domain.local"
    invoke-command -jobname whatsmyname -session $sess -scriptblock {
    #Pass in external parameter
    Param($myfirstname)
#Change #myfirstname ... there's more to it in the real script
$myfirstname = Jon
    $fullname = @()
    $fullname += $myfirstname
    $fullname += "Try"
    $fullname += "Feckta" # So this should be effectively $fullname = @(Jon,Try,Feckta) at this point
    # Now i need to pass back the changed/added variables
    } -Argumentlist ($myfirstname,$fullname)

    # Now when i attempt to show the data it just comes out blank
    write-out $fullname
write-out $myfirstname
```

Comment: that variable exists only in the remote session. You need to save it to a variable along with letting it write to the pipeline. Also, your JobName is not needed.

Comment: Sorry, yes, that is what i'm trying to find out, how* to pass the data back as it doesn't work the way i tried to do it (and i've tried various ways of passing it back, all with the incorrect syntax etc)...So i'm looking for the correct way of doing this.  I can remove the jobname if you want, i use it for keeping track of large numbers of jobs (figuring out which are taking longer or getting stuck etc...which allows me to add waiting periods after sending 10 or 1000 of a particular job...i'm sure there's better/more efficient ways but its the first way i tried);

Comment: Inside your scriptblock, don't save to a variable and just let it return the output. You can either just let it display, do something with that output immediately, or save it to a variable like so: `$fullName = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { "$myFirstName Try Feckta" } -Session $sess`, in your case, just write another variable to your script: `{ $fullname = @();$fullname += $myfirstname;$fullname += "Try";$fullname += "Feckta";$fullname }`.

Comment: So if i'm reading that right, i can pass one variable back, but not multiple (by setting a variable equal to the output)?  I can send multiple in, but not multiple out unless maybe the variable is an array(which in the example it is...)?  So $fullname is an array and to get the new $myfirstname back (Jon), i'd have to set it equal to the first entry in $fullname?

Comment: You can pass as many "variables" as you want back, but it'll only be the output of them and not the defined variables themselves. If you create a variable in your remote session called `$var`, that is only available in that remote scope and not yours. So if you have: `{ $var1 = 1; $var2 = 2; $var3 = 3 }`, these variables are not available for you to use in your scope. So yes, you can just assign the output directly to a variable and itll have your return. Although you can use variable assignment like this:`$1,$2 = icm { $1=1;$2=2;$1,$2} -cn localhost`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-ArgumentList` is for the variables that goes in.
There is no "byRef" here.

What you need to do is to assign your `Invoke-Command` statement to a variable.
From there, when you are ready to return your "multiple variables", you can return them as a hashtable so they are ready to use in your `Write-Host` statements.

**Example**

```
$Output = invoke-command -jobname whatsmyname -session $sess -scriptblock {
  #Pass in external parameter
  Param($myfirstname)
#  ... Your code here
  return @{
    MyFirstName = $myfirstname
    FullName    = $fullname
  }

} -Argumentlist ($myfirstname)

write-out $Output.fullname
write-out $Output.myfirstname
```

**Additional notes**

I am not passing the `$fullName` to the argument list since you did only define `Param($myFirstName)` and we established that yhe value would not go out and be assigned to the `$fullName` variable.